# opencart adding the new post input to $this->session

Tags: php, opencart

in `payment_method.tpl` of the checkout section of opencart template I have added an input named (and Id also) "`cheque_number`".

In `checkout.tpl`, I have modified the jQuery code that sends AJAX request so that the new input is also appended to currently wrapped data and thus is sent to the controller along with the other inputs.

However, I don't know what should I do in the controller (which is `payment_method/validate` as I think, to assign the new input value to the $this->session so that it gets added to the database too.

Currently, though it is sent by ajax, it is not known by confirm and checkout controller and thus is not saved in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to do :

**First**

add (after doing all necessary checks like if its empty or is of required length etc)

`$this->session->data['cheque_number'] = $this->request->post['cheque_number'];`

**Second**

In `confirm.php` controller add following line before `$this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);`

```
$data['cheque_number'] = $this->session->data['cheque_number'];
```

and again before doing this do all necessary validations you may want to

**Third**

Now i am assuming you already edited your `order` (or any other database table) to include your new field `cheque_number`

If so then edit `addOrder` function in your `Model/Checkout/Order`such that it also inserts your `cheque_number` along with other fields